# How to bind categories with ManagedBean and xhtml page

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I'm new to programming and I wanna ask: if I have a managedBean(with difference characteristics) and I want to add different categories, showing them on the xhtml page.. how can I bind those categories with managedBean and xhtml and put products in the right category after user add the product ?

here is a part of my xhtml code:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h2>New auction</h2>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Name:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.name}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.description}" />

                <h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{newAuctionWizard.cancel()}" />    
                <h:commandButton value="Details" action="newAuctionDetails" />  
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:messages style="color: red" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

and part of the java code:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -38089703767395198L;

private Long id;
@Size(min=2, max=30, message = "The auction's name: minim {min} and maximum {max} caractere")
private String name;
@Size(max=1000, message = "The auction's description must be of maximum {max} characters")
private String description;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Original price should be at least 1 RON")
@NotNull(message = "Highest Bid")
private Long originalPrice;
private String location;

private User owner;
private Bid highestBid;

private List<Bid> bids = new ArrayList<Bid>();
```

I want the user to be able to choose a category and put its product in the right category when adding an auction.. for each category shall I make a Java class ?

Thank you

Comment: if every product got a category i don't see a problem ??? please add some informations i am sure that an example will help

Comment: I ve done editing..the point is that when the user adds an auction, he/she shall be able to select a category and the added product to be put in the right category.. I don't know exactly how to make the binding

Comment: let me see if i understand the problem you want to make a list of products when a user choose a category is that what you mean???

Comment: no.. I want to make a list of categories(using select and option tag for example) and after the user picks the category I want to put the product in the right category.. for example when I list the categories in the xhtml page(home page) and pick a category from there I shall be able to see the coresponding products from that category

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this post i will try to answer about your question (even if it's not very clear for me)

in your category entity you will make the list of product that you will work with it will look like this

**categoryEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(QuerySessionLog.class)
@Table(name = "category")

....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,orphanRemoval = true)
private List<productEntity> listProducts ;
```

Don't forget the getter and setter of your list

and in your productEntity it will look like this

**productEntity.java**

```
...
@JoinColumn(name = "category")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private categoryEntity category;
```

one more time don't forget the getter and setter

and finnaly you can access to this data throw `category.listProducts`

to show your informations you can found various example in the primefaces web site [primefaces web site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) for example dataTable  ...

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Why not just refer to one of the many master-detail jpa Q/A on stackoverflow and a jpa tutorial? (Teaching to catch  fish instead of providing fish)

Comment: that's true it's the way to do it but the problem (i don't know if it's me or something else) i didn't understand the problem it's not clear i am waiting more informations to see what to do even if you are tottaly right a link to an older post will be greater

Comment: OK. Thank you. And in xhtml page I though of something like: <p> <label for="categories">Select unit types to enable on this map:</label> <select id="categories" name="categories" multiple> <option value="1" selected> category1 </option> <option value="2" selected> category2 </option> <option value="3" selected> category3 </option>  </select> </p>  ..  here I select the categories.. how to bind the select one with the one from managedBean when using xhtml ?..Thanks again

Comment: Then just comment and ask for clarification. Not provide 'guess' answers. Otherwise people are inclined to downvote your answers (I e.g. don't see a direct relation)

Comment: to do something like this go to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml it will offer you good option

Comment: @Kukeltje thank's for the clarification and DaianaB edit your question i hope it will help you to avoid downvote

Comment: and @Yagami.. your answer is ok because I want to make this mapping between categories and product(a category has same fields) :)

Comment: @DaianaB make as the answer of the question

Comment: but can I use @EventListener ?.. I am using javax, not spring .. thats why I am asking

Comment: create new question because tag is différente

Comment: OK.. i'll search meanwhile and if I don't find then i ll make a question